# serialize::Decodable is not implemented for the type `&str`

Tags: rust

I have a structure I want to be able to decode from json:

```
#[derive(RustcDecodable)]
struct MyStruct<'a> {
  aa: Option<&'a str>,
  bb: Option<u64>,
}
```

It doesn't compile:

```
error: the trait `rustc_serialize::serialize::Decodable` is not implemented for the type `&str` [E0277]
src/my_file.rs:31 #[derive(RustcDecodable)]
```

Why is that and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using serde? https://github.com/serde-rs/serde

Comment: So why are you using RustcDecodable instead of Decodable?

Comment: Note that the Rust style is 4-space indents.

Comment: @llogiq, because in the documentation they use it

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Not in the serde docs I linked above. But it doesn't matter. In fact looking into the auto-`derive` handling code, both are synonymous.

Comment: @llogiq, I'm not talking about serde.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you check out the documentation for [`Decodable`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/num/rustc_serialize/trait.Decodable.html), you can see a list of all the base types that can be decoded to. You'll notice that `&str` is not in the list. This is the root cause of your error.

Perusing that list shows that you can never decode to a borrowed type. *If* decoding to a string slice were possible, then the decoded struct would forever be tied to the lifetime of the input string and chances are that entire classes of decoders would become impossible — think of a decoder that directly reads from a file or a network stream, where the entire input data is never fully read in memory.

To fix it, switch your struct to own the data:

```
#[derive(RustcDecodable)]
struct MyStruct {
    aa: Option<String>,
    bb: Option<u64>,
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a [`Cow`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) to express that sometimes the data is owned, and sometimes it is borrowed:

```
#[derive(RustcDecodable)]
struct MyStruct<'a> {
    aa: Option<Cow<'a, str>>,
    bb: Option<u64>,
}
```